# Why the pthread_join is giving this error? [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'void**' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm following this application by my book, and I tried to copy this program and see what it does.

With my big surprise I found that it doesn't work!!

The program is the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TANTI 10
int parametroOUT;

void* codice(void *arg){
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    parametroOUT=(rand()%6)+1;
    pthread_exit((void*)&parametroOUT);
}

int main(){
    int dadoEstratto, *risultato=0;
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,codice,NULL);   
    pthread_join(t1, (void*) &risultato);
    printf("dado estratto: %d",*risultato);
    return 0;                                           
}
```

It returns an error at the line: `pthread_join(t1, (void*) &risultato);`.

The error is:

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'void**' [-fpermissive]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: That is looking more like `c` than `c++`.

Comment: Reverted the tag edit -- the error message indicates that OP is using a C++ compiler

Comment: @M.M that would be my mistake; thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by making this simple function, thank you to everyone who helped me

```css
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#define TANTI 10
int dadi[TANTI];
int i=0; 
void* codice(void *arg){

 while(i<TANTI){
    srand(time(NULL);
  dadi[i]=rand() % 6 + 1;
  printf("il dado estratto e': %d\n",dadi[i]);
  i++;
      }
 pthread_exit(0);     
        }
int main(){
 int dadoEstratto;
 pthread_t t1;
 pthread_create(&t1,NULL,codice,NULL);
 pthread_join(t1,NULL);
 return 0;           
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is wrong:

```
int *risultato=0;
...
pthread_join(t1, (void*) &risultato);
```

The [prototype for `pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) is:

```
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **value_ptr);
```

Note that it's a `void **`.  That's because the function used to start a thread returns a `void *`.  To be able to access the `void *` returned from the thread-start function, you need to pass the address of a `void *` so that `pthread_join()` can fill in the value:

```
void *risultato=0;
...
pthread_join(t1, &risultato);
```

Note that `risultato` is now the proper `void *`, and it's address is passed to `pthread_join()` by using the `&` "address-of" operator.

To get back to the `int` return value from your `codice()` function:

```
int *intPtr = ( int * ) risultato;
int value = *intPtr;
```

Comment: I tried but even in this case, like i said in the comment of the other answer, the output is strange

Answer (score 0):

The second argument should have type `void**`.

Here's what you should do:

```
void *risultato_voidp;
pthread_join(t1, &risultato_voidp);
resultato = static_cast<int*>(risultato_voidp);
```

Full example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define TANTI 10
int parametroOUT;
void* codice(void *arg){
    srand(time(NULL));
    parametroOUT=(rand()%6)+1;
    pthread_exit(static_cast<void*>(&parametroOUT));
}
int main(){
    int dadoEstratto, *risultato=0;
    void *risultato_voidp;
    pthread_t t1;
    int er;
    if(0!=(er=pthread_create(&t1,NULL,codice,NULL))) return errno=er,perror(0),1;
    pthread_join(t1, &risultato_voidp);
    risultato = static_cast<int*>(risultato_voidp);
    printf("dado estratto: %d\n",*risultato);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It returns this error: [Error] cast from 'void*' to 'int' loses precision [-fpermissive] in the int resultato=(int) risultato_voidp;

Comment: it work but it give me a strange value 
the output should be a number between 1 and 6, but the outbut is this                    0
4254373

Comment: nothing, i copy the entirely example you made but the output is the same

Comment: @GabrieleSantoro It's "working" correctly. It's a weird example though.  You can just print `parametroOUT` after the join, since it's a global, and forget about passing anything through `pthread_exit()`.

Comment: I've understood, I didin't think about put the print in the void. In a certain sense it was helpful, but i didn't undrestand why it made that number as output and not a number between 1 and 6. What is wrong?